# Unable to view the pdf file using src in iframe with document.write

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a href="" onclick="myFunction('atmosphere-07.pdf')" target="_blank">
    Click!
</a>
<br/>

function myFunction(name) {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=1200,height=600");
    myWindow.document.write(name);
    iFrame = document.getElementById('iFrame').src =name; 
    myWindow.document.write('<iframe id=iFrame src='name' width='1200' height='900' ></iframe>');
}
```

Want to open the pdf in new window with document.write call. Want to know how we can pass a variable in the above iframe context

Comment: I also want to hide the path of file from the user in new window

Comment: Third line of your code may not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```js
function myFunction(name) 
{
var myWindow = window.open(""); 
myWindow.document.write("<iframe id=iFrame src='"+name+"' width='1200' height='900' ></iframe>");
}
```

```html
<a href="" onclick="myFunction('atmosphere-07.pdf')" target="_blank">Click!</a> <br/>
```

It will not run here, on your application it will run, dont use run code snippet button.

Answer (score 0):

you can open directly, you don't need function for that.

Here is an example of what you need

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('atmosphere-07.pdf', '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes'); return false;">Click!</a>
```

This will open your PDF in full screen window

Comment: Thanks for the solution but this shows the path of file in new window, I want to hide it from the user.